# Count rows where value in row is also in previous row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, gaps-and-islands

I want to get a count where the contents of a value in one row is also in the previous row.

```
   Row | Item1 | Item2 | Item 3 |
   1   | Dog   | Cat   | Rat
   2   | Bird  | Cat   | Horse
   3   | Horse | Dog   | Rat
   4   | Bird  | Cat   | Horse
   5   | Horse | Bird  | Cat
```

Row 2 would increase the count of Cat because Cat is in row 1 and 2

Row 3 would increase the count of Horse because Horse is also in Row 2

Row 4 would increase the count of Horse because Horse is also in Row 3

Row 5 would increase the count of Horse AND Cat because both of those appear in row 4.

There can be a max of 100 items or SKU's and I can index on any or all fields. At any given time there's probably between 1000 and 2000 rows.

I can't even wrap my head around where to begin with this query other than "SELECT * FROM table WHERE"

Comment: Columns like Item1, Item2, etc. is poor design. You should have another table with 1 row per item.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Doing what you want with this design is possible, but will be incredibly verbose, you'll need 100 conditions.

Comment: Yep. Seriously consider revising your schema

Comment: Yes, columns like item1, item2 etc ARE poor design but sometimes you have to work with what you're given. @GMB MySQL version 5.6.41-84.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create table with all available unique values of SKU:

```sql
CREATE TABLE results(
  id    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

-- All fields should be listed here one-by-one.
INSERT IGNORE INTO results (select Item1 from example);
INSERT IGNORE INTO results (select Item2 from example);
INSERT IGNORE INTO results (select Item3 from example);
```

Previous row could be obtained by left join primary table again with itself, i.e. `LEFT JOIN example AS previous ON previous.id + 1 = example.id`.

After that we've to check that each unique result exists in example table within current row and in previous row and finally get this:

```sql
SELECT
  r.*,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN r.id IN (
      prv.Item1, prv.Item2, prv.Item3  -- All fields should be listed here.
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) AS total
FROM
  results AS r
LEFT JOIN
  example AS cur ON r.id IN (
    cur.Item1, cur.Item2, cur.Item3    -- All fields should be listed here.
  )
LEFT JOIN
  example AS prv ON prv.id + 1 = cur.id
GROUP BY
  r.id
ORDER BY
  cur.id
;
```

See working example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ebd85/1/0

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with window functions (available in MySQL 8.0).

An option is to unpivot the resultset, and then use `lag()` to check the previous record. Assuming that `id`s are always increasing by `1`, you can do:

```
select
    item,
    sum(case when id = lag_id + 1 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_consecutive
from (
    select
        t.*,
        lag(id) over(partition by item order by id) lag_id
    from (
        select id, item1 item from mytable
        union all select id, item2 from mytable
        union all select id, item3 from mytable
    ) t
) t
group by item
order by item
```

---

If you don't have an incremented column, you can generate one with `dense_rank()`:

```
select
    item,
    sum(case when new_id = lag_new_id + 1 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_consecutive
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lag(new_id) over(partition by item order by new_id) lag_new_id
    from (
        select
            t.*,        
            dense_rank() over(order by id) new_id
        from (
            select id, item1 item from mytable
            union all select id, item2 from mytable
            union all select id, item3 from mytable
        ) t
    ) t
) t
group by item
order by item
```

---

In **[this DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=36ba2b6745ea3b2de23efc098535838a)**, both queries return:

```
item  | cnt_consecutive
:---- | --------------:
Bird  |               1
Cat   |               2
Dog   |               0
Horse |               3
Rat   |               0
```

Comment: I really like some of the new features but this system is still running 5.6.41-84.1 so for that reason I accepted another answer as it runs on this older server.

Answer (score 0):

I see @frost-nzcr4 suggestion is very good and I was doing my own version quite similar to that yesterday. However, the approach I'm doing is a bit different because I didn't create a table specifically to store the unique value. Instead, I was doing similarly like @GMB `UNION` sub-query and it end up to be something like this :

```
SELECT B.row, A.allitem,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.allitem IN (C.Item1, C.Item2, C.Item3) THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 END) AS total
FROM

-- this sub-query will be dynamic and UNION will eliminate any duplicate
    (SELECT item1 AS allitem FROM mytable UNION
     SELECT item2 FROM mytable UNION
     SELECT item3 FROM mytable) AS A

LEFT JOIN mytable AS B ON A.allitem IN (B.Item1, B.Item2, B.Item3)
LEFT JOIN mytable AS C ON C.row + 1 = B.row
GROUP BY  A.allitem
ORDER BY  B.row;
```

Fiddle here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bUUEsaeyPpAMfR2bK1VpBb/2

As you can see this is exactly similar query to frost's suggestion with only minor modification. In the sub-query `allitem` value will be updated as long as there are new values inserted so you don't need to keep inserting new unique data into a separate table.

Also, this query would normally get `this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` error on MySQL v5.7 above unless you remove the sql_mode.